# Differential equation - How to solve it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the $x^5 \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y^3+2x^4$ differential equation. I've tried the $v=\frac{y}{x}$ substitution, and I've also tried to get $y'=x^\alpha G(\frac{y}{x})$ form; but I've failed. Could you give me a little hint?

Edit: The equation is $x^5 y'=y^3+2x^4 y$; the teacher missed out the last $y$.

Comment: $\frac{dy}{dy}$?

Comment: It supposed to be $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}$.

Comment: +1: For the difficult ODE. Could you check if you do not have a typo? Why do you think that this has an easy closed form solution? Maple/WolframAlpha are not able to give a solution. Maple is also not able to find symmetries of the ODE.

Comment: @MrYouMath It's a homework for the "Differential equations in physics 1" class. I've found out that it's Abel's equation. It seems to be a bit hard for a first-year class, I suppose.

Comment: Have you checked that you copied it correctly? Maybe it should be $2x^4y$ instead of $2x^4$. In which case it will be a Bernoulli differential equation.

Comment: @MrYouMath Yes, I've checked it several times. The Bernoulli's differential equation would be the good, I suppose, because we've learned that.Thank you for your confirmation; I've just sent an e-mail to the teacher about the possible error.

Comment: @MrYouMath you were right, it supposed to be $2x^4 y$. Thanks!